# Why axis = 0 returns columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, axis

Could you please advise why in code below when I use axis = 0, which means row, function returns columns (s and f) instead of rows?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'s':[1,2,3],'f':[7,8,9]})
def func(row):
    print(row)
a.apply(func,axis = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

refer to documentation here [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

here is the excerpt

```
> axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
>     Axis along which the function is applied:
>         0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
>         1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.
```